# OpenShift - List serviceaccounts with privileged scc

Tags: security, kubernetes, openshift

Is there an `oc` command (or other method) to list all service accounts that have been granted the `privileged` scc?

If I suspect `oc adm policy add-scc-to-user privileged -z SA_NAME` has been run against a number of service accounts, how can I check?  I know the call to undo this using `oc adm policy remove-scc-from-user ...`, but haven't found a command to list which accounts have been given an scc.

Answer (score 1):

You should not edit your scc. Simply to prevent typos. Use describe instead

```bash
oc describe scc privileged
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems I eventually stumbled on the answer to my own question.

Inspecting an scc shows the list of users that have the scc.

`oc edit scc privileged`

```
...
kind: SecurityContextConstraints
metadata:
   ...
   name: privileged
...
users:
 - system:admin
 - system:serviceaccount: SA_NAME1
 - system:serviceaccount: SA_NAME2
 - ...
```

What happens when adding privileged to an account (user or sa), it appears the opposite is really what happens, the user/sa is added to the scc.